# keeping custom attributes using a robust model layer with restangular

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I have an issue in which I wonder if Restangular has support for. I have a UserModel which is part of my model layer. It may have custom attributes that the server doesn't have in it's model and also behavior. I'm not clear if I'm able to use my custom User model, send it to the backend and when it returns transform it back to the UserModel object of my model layer so I still have the custom attribute and methods.

Here's the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/IlYcSRuX3GPWmewxniuq?p=preview

Where do I handle the transformation? Do I add the methods in the config block or should I add it via adding a response interceptor? What about custom attributes that the server might not send back to me? I haven't run across any good examples of this.

The UserInfoCntrl controller sends the UserModel object into the contactInformationService in my example.

Answer (score 1):

Some of this might be design choices, i.e. use what you think is best. However, a common pattern <sup>[citation needed ;)]</sup> would be to integrate the synchronization logic between client and server in the "model" service.

The `UserModel` service would then be responsible for providing the `User` object to the rest of the application, keeping it in sync with the server (perhaps via methods like `save()`, or perhaps automatically?). The service would then be the only module responsible for communicating with the server, at least when it comes to user objects. It can also automatically pull the user data from the server when instantiated.

The architecture feels very clean, at least to me.

I don't have any concrete examples that exactly suits your needs, but this [authentication service by Fnakstad springs to mind](https://github.com/fnakstad/angular-client-side-auth/blob/master/client/js/services.js). It maintains a object (actually a user object!) using `$http` and `$cookieStore`. Restangular is a bit more high-level than `$http`, but the self-contained service concept providing methods for manipulation and storing stands.

Comment: thanks this looks interesting. It's easy enough to just use mixins if necessary.